# How to Implement Parent-Child DataRelation on XtraGrid or UltraWinGrid with LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, xtragrid, ultrawingrid

I'm using LINQtoSQL to bring data for a *DevExpress XtraGrid* or a *Infragistics UltraWinGrid* and show a parent row with a [**+**] sign so that I could click and see the details (similar to a 2 level tree). I've been sucessful before using a `DataRelation` for my `DataSource` and then binding it just did it automatically. How can I achieve this using LINQ?

Example I've used in VB.NET for DataTables in a ADO.NET DataSource:

```
Dim rel As DataRelation = New DataRelation("Allocation",
        dsAllocation.Tables("tblParent").Columns("AllocKey"),
        dsAllocation.Tables("tblChild").Columns("AllocKey"), True)
```

This link is the best info I have reasearched, but looking for a more dynamic way of doing it.
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5495

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can use something that implements `IList<X>` as the `DataSource`. If `X` has a `IList<Y>` inside it, it'll display in the way you want. So as long as your LINQ query returns a list of `X` where each `X` contains a list of `Y`, it'll work.

*Note:* Since `IList` doesn't support notifications so if you want your grid to automatically update when adding/removing from the lists of `X` and `Y`, you'll want to use something that implements `IBindingList`.